# How do I remove this little line between font awesome icons?

Tags: html

[image]

I'd like to get rid of the little line between the two icons. Here's the code.

```
<a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-fw" style="font-size:24px"></i></a>
<a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-fw" style="font-size:24px"></i></a>
```

Comment: There appears to be a whitespace (tab, space, new line, etc.) between the two elements. Comment out the line break between the two anchor elements, or put them on the same line.

Comment: Doesn't happen for me http://www.bootply.com/4KqeecbftF

Comment: You're the one who put it there, as it shouldn't be there by default -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/JfGVE/1614/

Comment: And it looks like the underline text-decoration anchors get by default, try

    `a { text-decoration : none }`